# Adding html markup in datatables add row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to implement dynamically addrow in datatables but somehow i cant get it to work by adding html markup inside the newly added row and select data dont show up.

this is my js,

```
    $('#productselect').each(function(index, value){
        var initSelectpicker = $(this).selectpicker();
        $.getJSON('../../../html/data/productlist.php', function(data){

            initSelectpicker.html('');
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                initSelectpicker.append('<option value="' + val["prod_desc"] + '">'+ val["prod_desc"] + '</option>');
            });
            initSelectpicker.selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    }); //end flightselect
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add([
            counter +'.1',
            "<select class='form-control' id='productselect' data-live-search='true'>",
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ]).draw( false );

        counter++;
    } );

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
} );
```

Comment: Please elaborate more what you want to achieve. You can show us a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). And any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part of your script will only be called when your page is first loaded. That is why the select fields are populated with options from `productlist.php`.

So when you try to add more rows, the new select fields will have no options. What you can do is to call `productlist.php` when you try to add a new row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#addRow', function () {

        /*** GET ALL OPTIONS ***/
        $.getJSON('../../../html/data/productlist.php', function(data){
            var newoptions = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                newoptions .= '<option value="' + val["prod_desc"] + '">'+ val["prod_desc"] + '</option>';
            });
        });

        t.row.add([
            counter +'.1',
            '<select class="form-control" id="productselect" data-live-search="true">'+newoptions+'</select>',
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ]).draw( false );

        counter++;
    });

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The row adding works fine when I tried it in a fiddle.

You question seems to be "why doesn't the `<select>` in the new row have options".

Your code that seems intended for adding the content isn't being called after you add the row.  When the page is rendered, you're adding options to all of the `#productselect`s on the page, but that control doesn't exist yet.  You have to call your code to add the options only after the select itself has been added.

Separately, you're going to have problems because your select control has an `id` attribute, and if the user enters multiple rows then you'll have a document containing more than one element with the same `id`, which is a no-no.